# Setting locations.ini in WebPageTest private instance

Tags: web

I am trying to setup a private instance of WebPageTest using r2.14. I have stumbled on putting correct information in locations.ini. Here is what I have tried till now

1. Used locations.sample.ini sample data just to see how it goes and it shows me only 'Dallas' location with IE instance.
2. Modified sample value as per documentation written in file. Unless I add remote configuration to a particular location, it will not show up in drop down list in browser.
3. Tried example provided at https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/private-instances/locations and http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/09/18/how-to-create-an-all-in-one-webpagetest-private-instance/ but no locations show up on drop down list in browser.

Can someone with prior experience please point me to what I am doing wrong else please to a good resource and I will do the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to make it work. Links I provided in the example are correct and set locations.ini file correctly.

However what happens is that unless test agents are configured and start polling server for tests, list will not populate them. I was not setting up test agents instead was stuck trying to make server work.

Installed and configured test agents and list got populated.

Comment: I struggled with setting this up, too. That's why I've put together a how-to guide on [setting up WebPageTest server and test agent](http://shades-of-orange.com/post/2015/11/14/How-to-Quickly-Set-Up-a-Private-WebPageTest-Server-And-Client) that contains all the information you need to set this up successfully :-)

Comment: I am struggling with my settings. Is there any documentation (proper one).